# How to retrieve Session key from Skyscanner API post request - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, skyscanner

In my app I want to fetch Live Price by Flight Details for this I have used [**SkyScanner API**](http://business.skyscanner.net/portal/en-GB/Documentation/FlightsLivePricingList). I have read the documentation before obtained data I have to create Live Pricing Service Session. Which can be created by post request to api and then it provide `SessionKey` by using this `SessionKey` and `apiKey` I can retrived the data. So How can I get Sessionkey as I understood it must be provided by API Server.

Here is my try:

```
require 'json'
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'


  post_params = { 
    :apiKey => "[API_KEY]",
    :country => "GB",
    :currency => "GBP",
    :locale => "en-GB",
    :adults =>1,
    :children => 0,
    :infants => 0,
    :originplace => '11235',
    :destinationplace => '13554',
    :outbounddate => '2015-05-19',
    :inbounddate => '2015-05-26',
    :locationschema => 'Default',
    :cabinclass => 'Economy',
    :groupPricing => true
  }


sessionkey_request = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0'), post_params )
get_data= "http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0/?apiKey=[API_KEY]"
puts sessionkey_request.inspect
temp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(get_data)).body
# puts temp
```

In console I get

```
<Net::HTTPCreated 201 Created readbody=true> # sessionkey_request.inspect
```

Not getting **SessionKey** in response without it I can not retrieved data. Please guide me where I do mistake. I appreciate for solution.

Fore more details and live result [**Check Demo**](http://business.skyscanner.net/portal/en-GB/Documentation/FlightsLivePricingQuickStart) by API

**Note:** I have check [**gem 'skyscanner '**](https://github.com/axic/skyscanner) but it doesn't provide any method for Live Price. It provide Browse Cache methods.

Comment: I replaced your actual API Key with a placeholder as it's probably not a good idea for it to be public.

Comment: @martincarlin87 : I am aware about secret key should not posted but it's not my real APi-key. I have taken it from demo site only. It's public. Anyways Thanks :)

Comment: ah, ok. I'm not familiar with the Skyscanner API but if you are getting a 201 status then you can't be far away from getting the session key but from reading the docs it  says `A successful response contains no content. The URL to poll the booking details is specified in the Location header of the response.`. Have you tried something like `puts temp["location"]` or whatever the response object is?

Comment: as I have declared I am getting `{}` as `temp` object. I have inspect on it

Comment: yes but as the docs say, the body is empty when you have a successful request, the session key you need is in the form of the url for future requests but it's in the header and not the body.

Comment: I know requested successful but without knowing `sessionKey` how can I retrieved data. Somebody has post the solution let me try.

Comment: @HetalKhunti : as martincarlin87 informed you, you  were very near with the solution. I have post the answer please check it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the doc:

> A successful response contains no content. The URL to poll the booking
>   details is specified in the Location header of the response

so try this:

```
sessionkey_request["location"]
```

I have test it on my system and it returns me:

```
http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0/8e28260becd3441ca4e865396e224e7d_ecilpojl_EC71481935CEBB7EAF661BC24940D01D
```

last part is your `sessionKey` which you can use for `GET` request. If you want only last part(sessionKey) then you can retrieved it by:

```
 > url = "http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0/8e28260becd3441ca4e865396e224e7d_ecilpojl_EC71481935CEBB7EAF661BC24940D01D"
 > url.split('/').last
 => "8e28260becd3441ca4e865396e224e7d_ecilpojl_EC71481935CEBB7EAF661BC24940D01D"
```

Comment: Oh.. man you save my day. I was sooo near with this but didn't try this way. Thanks now it works like charm. Thanks a lots

Comment: @GaganGami I'm also facing the same issue with status code 415. For testing purpose. i requested through POSTMAN. Can you guide me to fix the issue?

Comment: @i-Droid: sure can you post question on SO, with what have you done/ tried so far, and also don't forget to post your code

Comment: @GaganGami Sure but i didn't start code yet. What i did was Created an account and tried to create a session using POSTMAN. Is this right or i must request through my applicaion??