# where is SkyScanner SessionKey?

Tags: android, http, skyscanner

first SkyScanner Document say

Response Details

A successful response contains no content. The URL to poll the booking details is specified in the Location header of the response.

**and**

[How to retrieve Session key from Skyscanner API post request - Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30188579/how-to-retrieve-session-key-from-skyscanner-api-post-request-ruby)
 this link say response successful -> Location header return "sessionKey"

My Problem is response successful but Location header return null...

I use **Okhttp** lib and

Here is my code

```
public String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
    try {
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);

        Request request = new Request
                .Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(body)
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencode")
                .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();


        Log.v("Response", "code : " + response.code());
        Log.v("Response", "message : " + response.message());
        Log.v("Response", "location : " + response.header("location"));
        return response.body().string();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

And My log

> 10-20 20:01:00.698 22202-22408/com.example.park.myapplication
>   V/Response: ***code : 200***
>
> 10-20 20:01:00.698 22202-22408/com.example.park.myapplication
>   V/Response: **message : OK**
>
> 10-20 20:01:00.698 22202-22408/com.example.park.myapplication
>   V/Response: **location : null**

What should I do? please find my Session Key...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change lib Okhttp -> HttpurlConnection...

try {
            url = new URL(u);
            HttpURLConnection connection =                           (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

```
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setConnectTimeout(500 * 1000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(500 * 1000);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);


        String Parameters = "apiKey=" + apiKey +
                "&country=UK" +
                "&currency=GBP" +
                "&locale=en-GB" +
                "&originplace=EDI" +
                "&destinationplace=LHR" +
                "&outbounddate=2016-11-01" +
                "&intbounddate=2016-11-08" +
                "&locationschema=Iata" +
                "&adults=1";
        //Parameter 컨텐트 길이 넘겨주는 부분
        byte[] postData = Parameters.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        int postDataLength = postData.length;
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postDataLength));
        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
        os.write(postData);
        os.flush();



        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```